# how create pandas data frame from csv, and stay numerical values as string, with no change them to int?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

python

Is there any way to create pandas data frame from csv file with no convert numerical values to int?

Example:

At csv file save values as '0123456'.
When I try to read the table, the value convert to int, then first zero value '0' removed, and I see it as 123456.

Thank you

Comment: Use dtypes. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: yes, I already used it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can use

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, optional
>   Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’} Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

so, you can use `pd.read_csv(..., dtype='str', ...)`, or be more precise and specify it per column.